# How to stop a form from submitting when using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote this JavaScript code to tell me if two email addresses do not match. That part works just fine.

The problem I am having is that, even if the email adresses do not match, it will still let me submit the forms.

I am just wondering how would I make it where you can not submit the form if the email addresses do not match.

Here is my code:

```
"use strict";

// global variables
var profile = {};

// validate entered password
function validateEmail() {
   var email1Input = document.getElementById("email");
   var email2Input = document.getElementById("email_retype");
   email1Input.value = email1Input.value.toLowerCase();
   email2Input.value = email2Input.value.toLowerCase();
   var errorDiv = document.getElementById("emailError");
   try {
        
        if (email1Input.value.localeCompare(email2Input.value) !== 0) {
            throw "The e-mails do not match";
        }
              // remove any password error styling and message
              email1Input.style.background = "";
              email2Input.style.background = "";
              errorDiv.style.display = "none";
              errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
             
           }
       catch(msg) {
          // display error message
          errorDiv.style.display = "block";
          errorDiv.innerHTML = msg;
          // change input style
          email1Input.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
          email2Input.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";  
       }
}

function createEventListeners() {
   var email2Input = document.getElementById("email_retype");
   if (email2Input.addEventListener) {    
      email2Input.addEventListener("change", validateEmail, false); 
   } else if (email2Input.attachEvent) {
      email2Input.attachEvent("onchange", validateEmail);
   }
   
   var lodgings = document.getElementsByName("lodgings");
   if (lodgings[0].addEventListener) {
      for (var i = 0; i < lodgings.length; i++) {
         lodgings[i].addEventListener("change", registerLodging, false);
      }
   } else if (lodgings[0].attachEvent) {
      for (var i = 0; i < lodgings.length; i++) {
         lodgings[i].attachEvent("onchange", registerLodging);
      }
   }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
   window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by change this line :

```
 email1Input.value.localeCompare(email2Input.value) !== 0
```

to :

```
if(email1Input.value != email2Input.value) {
say no
}
```